# Power BI Report using Facebook real time data

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, powerbi, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to show the insights(page view, comments, posts, etc) data of my Facebook page in a Power BI dashboard, that is embedded into my web-page, I am able to show the dummy report by downloading the Facebook page CSV report. If I have to real-time update the dashboard what is the procedure for that.

Answer (score 0):

there are at least two options:

1. Connector
2. API

#### Connector

At this very moment there might be an issue connecting Power BI to Facebook but in general you should be able to use the built-in [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-tutorial-facebook-analytics).
Please note that with the connector, once your report is published in Power BI Service it will not refresh data in real-time, instead in semi-real time. For example, you can define to refresh the data source up to 8 times a day (using Pro license) or even more if you have Enterprise Premium Capacity.

#### API

Instead, if you really need to deal with real-time data the alternative is using the API offered in the [real-time streaming service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming) of Power BI.